# How to add more than one Linear Layout to single ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just want to ask that can we add more than one linear layout inside one scrollview as i read somewhere that you can have only one linear layout. here i am copy paste my xml code in which i want scrolling.

```
    <TextView 
        android:text=" First Name :"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtd_fname"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:ems="15"/>

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView 
        android:text="Last Name:"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtd_lname"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:ems="15"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView 
        android:text="Disease Name:"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtd_disease"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView 
        android:text="Mobile No:"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtd_mno"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:ems="10" android:inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView 
        android:text="Clinic  No:"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

                <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtd_cno"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:ems="10" android:inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <TextView 
        android:text="Home No :"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       />

                <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtd_hno"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:ems="10" android:inputType="number"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView 
        android:text= "Reminder:"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spn_reminder"
        android:layout_width="167dp"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:entries="@array/reminder" />
 </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Appointment On Date-Time:"/>

<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/rgapp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rdyes" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Yes"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rdno" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:checked="true" android:text="No"/>
</RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:id="@+id/ll_doc_1">      
    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/time1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <DatePicker android:id="@+id/Date1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:calendarViewShown="false"/>

     </LinearLayout>  
       <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDsave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/save"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Scrollview can have only one direct child. So if you want to put more than one linear layout in a single scrollview, you should put all those layouts inside one linear / relative layout and then put that layout inside a scrollview.

Comment: Yes. Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html. You can put only one child in scrollview. So if you want to put 2 layouts A and B in single scrollview, then you should put A and B inside layout C. Then you can put C inside a scrollview. See the answer. It explains the same

Comment: Mention not. Ask if you still have any doubt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scrollview can have only one direct child. you should put all those layouts inside one linearlayout and then put that layout inside a scrollview.

Try like this

```
<ScrollView 
   <LinearLayout     /// mainlayout 
       <LinearLayout   /// childlayout 1
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout   /// childlayout 2
       </LinearLayout>

       <LinearLayout   /// childlayout 3
       </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView
```

Comment: is it possible to have two mainlayouts inside scrollview?

Comment: No.. scroll view allows only one child (view)...so one thing ... add one LinearLayout in scroll view then add required layouts to that layout.

Comment: you mean to say as per your answer i cant create two main layouts in single scrollview? and you are saying to add childviews in single mainlayout? is it?

Comment: yes.. create one parent layout in scroll view then add more layouts in that parent

Comment: so as per my need,i need to add two main layouts..and it is not possible..right?